# Proving a system does not have any integer solution

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, arithmetic, matrix-equations, integers

Let's consider the following diophantine system:

$$(\mathscr S)\quad\begin{cases} 2x+y\in a\mathbb{Z} \\ x-2y\in a\mathbb{Z},\end{cases}$$

where $a\in\mathbb Z$ is a large integer.

We know that $x,y$ are integers such that

$$x,y\in\{0,\ldots,a\}\qquad(\star)$$

and such that

$$(x,y)\notin\{(0,0),(0,a),(a,0),(a,a)\}.\qquad(\star\star)$$

---

> **The question.**
>
> Can we show that $(\mathscr S)$ has no such integers solutions?

---

**What I tried.**

We can rewrite the system with matrices:

$$MX=aK$$

where

$$M=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & -2\end{pmatrix},$$

$$X=\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix},$$

and

$$K=\begin{pmatrix} k \\ k'\end{pmatrix}$$

where $k\in\{0,1,2\}$ and $k'\in\{-1,0\}$ since $(\star)$ and $(\star\star)$.

We have $\det M=-5$, but I don't know how to proceed from here...

*Any help or leads would be much appreciated.*

Comment: You would normally not allow $x,y$ to equal $a$ because $0$ to $a-1$ form a complete set of residues.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes indeed, but here they can...

Comment: That lets you get rid of the double starred line.

Comment: @RossMillikan I don't understand. I can have $(x,y)=(a,7)$ or $(x,y)=(0,5)$, but I can't have $(x,y)=(0,a)$.

Comment: You want to avoid $(0,0)$ and $(0,a)$ is equivalent $\bmod a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add twice the first to the second, then subtract twice the second from the first, you get
$$(\mathscr S)\quad\begin{cases} 5x\in a\mathbb{Z} \\ 5y\in a\mathbb{Z},\end{cases}$$
We can solve it for $a=5,$ finding $$x=1,\ y=3\\
x=2,\  y=1\\
x=3,\ y=4\\
x=4,\ y=2$$
 as a solutions.  For $a$ a multiple of $5$ you can multiply these solutions by $\frac a5$.  If $a$ is not a multiple of $5$ the first lines show there is no solution.

Comment: Can you please explain: "if $a$ is not a multiple of $5$, the first lines  show there is no solution"?

Comment: If $a$ is not a multiple of $5$, the only ways to satisfy the first line are $x=0$ and  $x=a$.  Similarly for $y$.  You have excluded all those cases in your doubled starred line.